# Clearing Clipboard Data in Android

Tags: android, clipboarddata, clipboardmanager

I'm trying to clear the Clipboard data in android as follow but its not clearing it.

```
ClipboardManager clipman = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
clipman.setPrimaryClip(null);
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since API 11 ClipboardManager (as old ClipboardManager class is deprecated.)

```
ClipboardManager clipBoard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
clipBoard.setPrimaryClip(data);
```